# Beautiful Soup won't let me parse a variable containing HTML

Tags: python, parsing, email, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to pretty print an HTML email which I have stored in a variable, but I keep getting an error from BS4 that says it is expecting a string.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import imaplib
import email


mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

username = raw_input('USERNAME (email):')
password = raw_input('PASSWORD: ')

try:
    mail.login(username, password)
    print "Logged in as %r !" % username
except: 
    imaplib.error
    print "Log in failed."

mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(FROM "tiffany@e.tiffany.com")')
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

print email_message

html = email_message
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()
```

Here is the printed HTML email I am working from: http://pastebin.com/qfAHwkdV

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tiff.py", line 34, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.builder.prepare_markup(markup, from_encoding))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 139, in prepare_markup
    dammit = UnicodeDammit(markup, try_encodings, is_html=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 203, in __init__
    self._detectEncoding(markup, is_html)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 372, in _detectEncoding
    xml_encoding_match = xml_encoding_re.match(xml_data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Why am I unable to pss the HTML to a variable to parse with BS4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation on `.message_from_string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string), this does not return a string, but a message object. `BeautifulSoup()` expects a string (or buffer).

Perhaps do `soup = BeautifulSoup(str(html))` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(html))`

Comment: thanks this worked! but it stripped almost everything out of the prettified email. any thoughts?

Comment: @user1887261 I'm sorry, I've never worked with the email module